# Why is the canonical bundle of a hypersurface of degree $d>4$ in $\mathbb {CP}^3$ ample?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $F\in \mathbb C[z_0, z_1,z_2, z_3]$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ and let $X := \{x \in \mathbb CP^3 \ | \ F([x]) = 0\}$.

> I have read that if $d>4 $ then the canonical bundle $K_X$ is *ample* and I would like to undestand why.

By adjunction, $K_X = (d-4) H_X$ where $H_X$ is the restriction of the line bundle $H$ associated to an hyperplane in $\mathbb {CP}^3$.
Consequently $K_X^2 = d (d-4)^2$.
I also have computed $b_2 = d^3 −4d^2 +6d−2$ and $b^+ = \frac{(d-3)(d-2)(d-1)}{3}+1$.

I know of the Nakai-Mosheizon criterion: $K_X$ is ample iif $K_X^2 >0$ and $K_X \cdot C >0$ for all curves $C $ in X. I don't see however how I can verify the latter property.
Maybe we can prove this starting from the definition of ample?

Comment: Can you prove that if $L \to X$ is ample and $Y \subset X$ is a hypersurface then $L_{|Y} \to Y$ is ample? That might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  Gunnar Þór Magnússon for suggesting the following approach.

Let  $s_0,\dots, s_n \in Hol(X, L)$ be a basis of holomorphic functions.
The map $i_L : X\to \mathbb P(Hol(X,L))^*\simeq \mathbb{CP}^{n}$ can be written using a local trivialization $U_\alpha$ of $L$ as
$i_L(x) = [s_{0,\alpha}(x): \dots :s_{n,\alpha}(x)]\in \mathbb{CP}^n$.

*Assume that L is very ample*, then $i_L$ is an embedding.

If we consider $L|_Y\to Y$ where $Y\subset X$ is complex submanifold, then we can take as basis for $Hol(Y,L|_Y)$, $s_0|_Y,\dots, s_n|_Y, \dots, s_N$.
Notice that it is possible that some of the sections coincide over $Y$.
Nevertheless the map
$i_{L|_Y}(y) = [s_{0,\alpha}(y): \dots :s_{N,\alpha}(y)]\in \mathbb{CP}^{N}$
will be an embedding because $(i_{L})|_Y$ is an embedding (even if some sections coincide over $Y$, there will be enough sections to separate the points of $Y$ thus the map will be injective, opennes follows in a similar manner).

*Consequently $L$ (very) ample implies that $L|_Y$ is (very) ample too*.

---

Now returing to the original problem, it is enough to prove that $H = \mathcal{O}(1)\to \mathbb {CP}^3$  is ample (which will imply that $kH$ is ample for $k>0$).
We note that  $H$ is very ample, indeed the holomorphic sections induced by $z_0,z_1, z_2, z_3\in \mathbb{C}[z_0,\dots, z_3]$ induce an the inclusion
$i_H([z_0:\dots, z_3]) = [z_0:\dots: z_3]\in \mathbb{CP}^3$.

Comment: You mean $\mathscr O(+1)$, of course.